# How to manage different TwitterStream from different Thread

Tags: java, twitter4j, twitter-streaming-api

i'm trying to execute different Thread using different TwitterStream object with an single authentication:

```
public class Support {
    private static final String accessToken = "xxxxxxx";
    private static final String accessTokenSecret = "xxxxxxx";
    public static final AccessToken token = new AccessToken(accessToken, accessTokenSecret); 
    private static final String consumerKey = "xxxxxxx";
    private static final String consumerSecret = "xxxxxxx";
    private static final Configuration conf = new ConfigurationBuilder().setOAuthConsumerKey(consumerKey).setOAuthConsumerSecret(consumerSecret).build(); 
    public static TwitterStreamFactory factory = new TwitterStreamFactory(conf); 
}
```

In every Thread i do:

```
public MyThread1(){
   this.twitterStream = Support.factory.getInstance(Support.token);
}
public void run(){
        StatusListener listener = ... ;
        twitterStream.addListener(listener);
        FilterQuery fq = new FilterQuery();
        fq.track(new String[]{"hashtag1","hashtag2"});
        twitterStream.filter(fq);
    }

public MyThread2(){
   this.twitterStream = Support.factory.getInstance(Support.token);
}
public void run(){
        StatusListener listener = ... ;
        twitterStream.addListener(listener);
        FilterQuery fq = new FilterQuery();
        fq.track(new String[]{"hashtag3","hashtag4"});
        twitterStream.filter(fq);
    }
```

But it gives me authentication error.. multiple request of the same authentication. How can i solve?

Comment: I believe you can only have one open connection at a time using the same credentials

Comment: so do u think that i need to track every keyword inside a single filter?

Comment: That is what i did.  I have one stream and add queries to it.  The callback comes to all threads and each thread checks to see if its relevant for them.  Might not be the best way but it works.

Comment: in which way you check if is rilevant for him or not? can you give me some example code please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I did it:

```
public class MyTwitterApp implements {

private Twitter twitter;
private Query query;

public MyTwitterApp (){
    twitter = TwitterFactory.getSingleton();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyTwitterApp twitterApp  = new MyTwitterApp();
    twitterApp.getStreamingTweets();

}

public void getStreamingTweets(){
    StatusListener listener = new StatusListener(){
        public void onStatus(Status status) {
                handleStatus(status);
        }
        public void onDeletionNotice(StatusDeletionNotice statusDeletionNotice) {}
        public void onTrackLimitationNotice(int numberOfLimitedStatuses) {}
        public void onException(Exception ex) {ex.printStackTrace(); }
        public void onScrubGeo(long arg0, long arg1) {}
        public void onStallWarning(StallWarning arg0) {}
    };
    twitter.addListener(listener);
    FilterQuery fq = new FilterQuery();
    fq.count(0);
    fq.track(new String[]{"#MyHashTag"});
    twitter.filter(fq);
}

protected void handleStatus(Status tweet) {
    if(tweet.isRetweet()){
        return;
    }
    if(isMyHashTagTweet(tweet)){
        //do something with tweet here      
    }       
}

private boolean isMyHashTagTweet(Status tweet) {
    HashtagEntity[] htes = tweet.getHashtagEntities();
    for(HashtagEntity hte : htes){
        if(hte.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("myhashtag")) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

Each thread will contain something like this.

```
twitter = TwitterFactory.getSingleton();
```

Will make sure you are reusing the same connection each time.

```
twitter.addListener(listener);
```

Will add a listener so that you will get called back to this thread (but you will get called back from every query added)

```
twitter.filter(fq);
```

Will add a new search query to follow.

```
isMyHashTagTweet(tweet)
```

Will check to make sure that the tweet returned by all queries live in your twitterStream are relevant for your current thread